# List of Generics

Tags: java, list, generics

So I have a simple Java class DatedValue as follows:

```
public class DatedValue<V> implements Comparable<DatedValue>{

private V value;
private Date date;

public DatedValue(V value, Date date){
    this.value = value;
    this.date = date;
}

public V getValue(){
    return value;
}

public Date getDate(){
    return date;
}

@Override
public int compareTo(DatedValue dv) {
    return date.compareTo(dv.date);
}

}
```

And I have a list of objects of this class, as follows:

```
List<DatedValue<Float>> list =  new ArrayList<DatedValue<Float>>();
```

And I can populate this list with DatedValue<Floats>.

However, when I try to use the getValue function of a DatedValue from this list, it returns an Object rather than a Float.  I cannot for the life of me figure out why.

Any help is appreciated!

Edit:

Here is the entire context.  It will probably be very confusing.

```
public class MomentumFormula {

private List<DatedValue<Float>> pricedata;
private List<Integer> upmomentumdata;
private List<Integer> downmomentumdata;

public MomentumFormula(String stock, GregorianCalendar startdate,
        GregorianCalendar enddate){
    pricedata = new ArrayList<>();
    upmomentumdata = new ArrayList<>();
    downmomentumdata = new ArrayList<>();
    DBManager db = new DBManager("stockdata");
    try{
        Connection dbconn = db.getConnection();
        Statement stmt = dbconn.createStatement();
        String tablename = stock;
        if(tablename.contains(".")){
            tablename = new StringBuilder("stock").
                    append(tablename.replace(".", "period")).toString();
        }else{
            tablename = new StringBuilder("stock").
                    append(tablename).toString();
        }
        ResultSet rs = stmt.executeQuery(new StringBuilder(
                "SELECT * FROM ").append(tablename).
                append(" WHERE date BETWEEN STR_TO_DATE('").
                append((startdate.get(Calendar.MONTH) + 1)).append(", ").
                append(startdate.get(Calendar.DATE)).append(", ").
                append(startdate.get(Calendar.YEAR)).
                append("', '%m, %d, %Y')").append(" AND ").
                append("STR_TO_DATE('").
                append((enddate.get(Calendar.MONTH) + 1)).append(", ").
                append(enddate.get(Calendar.DATE)).append(", ").
                append(enddate.get(Calendar.YEAR)).
                append("', '%m, %d, %Y')").
                toString());
        while(rs.next()){                
            pricedata.add(new DatedValue<>(rs.getFloat("close"),
                    rs.getDate("date")));
        }
        Collections.sort(pricedata);
        if(pricedata.size() != 0){
            DatedValue<Float> first = pricedata.get(0);
            DatedValue<Float> highesthigh = new DatedValue<>(
                    first.getValue(), first.getDate());
            DatedValue<Float> lowestlow = new DatedValue<>(
                    first.getValue(), first.getDate());
            if(highesthigh.getValue() > lowestlow.getValue()){}
            for(DatedValue v : pricedata){
                if(v.getValue() > highesthigh.getValue()){
                    highesthigh = v;
                }
            }
        }
    }catch(Exception e){
        System.out.println("Exception in MomentumFormula");
        System.out.println(e.toString());
    }
}

}
```

The error occurs on the line:

```
if(v.getValue() > highesthigh.getValue()){

Exception in MomentumFormula
java.lang.RuntimeException: Uncompilable source code - bad operand types for binary operator '>'
  first type:  java.lang.Object
  second type: java.lang.Float
```

Comment: Show us your callsite and comipler error.

Comment: Most likely you are using a raw `DatedValue` somewhere in code you haven't shown.  Please show how you are accessing your `DatedValue` from the list.

Comment: When you get DatedValue from the list, don't forget to set it's generic type to Float as well.

Comment: That was the problem!  I changed 
for(DatedValue : pricedata)
to
for(DatedValue<Float> v : pricedata)
and it worked.  I guess I just assumed that Java would reference this information automatically.

Comment: Also @Barmar: Not only is your comment unhelpful, but it is also irrelevant.  I have not even looked at JavaScript since middle school (I am a college grad)...

Comment: @NicholasRestifo You had the `javascript` tag on the question. I changed it to `java` for you.

Comment: Maybe it was just a misclick, I'm sorry for the attitude.

Comment: Hm, either that or an auto-correct error.  Well, no harm no foul I suppose.

Comment: possible duplicate of [What is a raw type and why shouldn't we use it?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2770321/what-is-a-raw-type-and-why-shouldnt-we-use-it)

Comment: `implements Comparable<DatedValue<?>>`

Answer (score 0):

You are using a "raw" `DatedValue` there. That means the compiler doesn't know a specific type for the result of `getValue()`, and treats it as an `Object`. Because the relational operator `>` is only defined for numeric operands, you should get a compilation error.

To fix it, specify a type parameter for your `DatedValue`. In fact, fix every case where you have a warning that says, "DatedValue is a raw type. References to generic type DatedValue should be parameterized."

The `for`-loop that is causing trouble should include a type parameter:

```
for(DatedValue<Float> v : pricedata){
  if(v.getValue() > highesthigh.getValue()){
    highesthigh = v;
  }
}
```

There are a number of other problems with the `DateValue` class.

The `implements` clause should be `implements Comparable<DatedValue<V>>`, and the `compareTo()` method should be declared as `public int compareTo(DatedValue<V> dv)`. This will eliminate the raw type warnings.

If you implement `Comparable`, you should also override `equals()` and `hashCode()` so that they yield consistent results. That implies that your `compareTo()` method should fall back to comparing `value` when the dates are the same.

Also, you directly access fields instead of using the accessor methods you've defined. You should declare `DateValue` to be `final` so that these accessors cannot be overridden.